# How to detect if a message is a embed(discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

Basically I'm trying to detect if a message sent was a embed and I don't know how to go about it.
Discord.js.Im trying to send a message in a channel a message that was deleted but i dont want to message in a channel if the deleted message was a embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property .embeds in message class that return an array with the embeds:

```
if(message.embeds.length > 0) // message have a embed
```